# Weight of a tensor density

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, metric-tensor

Is there any freedom in choosing the weight of a tensor density?

I have seen in some papers that they introduce a tensor density made from metric with a special weight.
There is a tensor density with the weight of **$\frac{-1}{2}$** :

$$\overset{\sim}{g_{ab}} = \sqrt{({\det g})} ^{\frac{-1}{2}}~~g_{ab}$$

In the paper *The geometry of free fall and light propagation* by Ehlers and his colleagues ([*Gen. Relativ. Gravit.* **44** no. 6, pp. 1587–1609 (2012)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10714-012-1353-4)), on page 1599 there is an example.

You can also look at the relation **$2.4$** of [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2841).

I don't understand why this special weight is chosen for the tensor density constructed from metric.

Comment: Who is "they"??

Comment: I mean some articles.

Comment: Ah. Perhaps you could *cite* these papers? Maybe then someone could answer your question.

Comment: @KyleKanos:I added an example.

Comment: Comment to the question (v4): Are you asking (i) if the same fixed physical tensor density could be assigned different tensor weights, or (ii) if it is possible to modify a physical tensor density, so that it has any weight, that one would like?

Comment: @Qmechanic:For (i),I think the answer is yes(I have seen two tensor densities constructed from metric with different weights). My question is mostly related to (ii).

Comment: Question (i) was meant to be talking about the same tensor density, not two tensor densities. The answer to (i) is then _No_ (modulo possible conventions). Question (ii) is not really well-defined, since it depends on context and setting, e.g. whether a metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ is available or not.

Comment: @Qmechanic:A tensor density is characterized by its weight. I don't understand what you mean by same tensor density with different weights? Have you seen the example I mentioned in the question? Do you have any idea why that tensor density is defined? It is defined in d'Inverno 1992(Introducing Einstein's Relativity) a gothicized tensor which is a tensor density of weight 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these particular cases, the authors are interested in the conformal structure, i.e. lightcone structure, of the manifold.  A conformal structure can be defined by an equivalence class of metrics, all of which are related to each other by a conformal transformation,
$$g_{ab}\sim e^{\omega(x)}\bar{g}_{ab}$$
A nice way to characterize a conformal structure is to say it is just the tensor density of weight $-1/2$ that you mention.  Under a conformal transformation, the metric determinant changes by
$$g\mapsto e^{4\omega}\bar{g},$$
so you can see that the density weight is chosen so that the tensor density $\tilde{g}_{ab}$ is invariant under the conformal transformation.  If you were in dimension other than $4$, you would choose the weight to be $-2/d$, to maintain this invariance under conformal transformations.

Comment: Have you worked on EPS?

Comment: @Dory No, the papers you posted were the first time I've seen that line of research.

Answer (score 1):

The weight would be the power of the Jacobian used in the transformation law. For an ordinary tensor the weight is then zero and for a tensor density it is one. In principle you can define quantities with any weight but you should call them something other than a tensor density.

Note that I have not read your reference because it is behind a firewall.

Comment: An example is the relation 2.4 of this article(http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2841).